# Intuitive motivation for BFGS update

Tags: optimization, iterative-method, nonlinear-programming

I am teaching a numerical analysis survey class and am seeking motivation for the BFGS method for students with limited background/intuition in optimization!

While I don't have time to prove rigorously that everything converges, I'm looking to give a reasonable motivation for why the BFGS Hessian update might appear.  As an analogy, Broyden's root-finding method (my writeup is [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs205a-13-fall/assets/notes/chapter7.pdf)) can be motivated by asking that your current approximation of the Jacobian minimizes the difference $\|J_k-J_{k-1}\|^2_{\textrm{Fro}}$ with the old Jacobian subject to the constraint that it takes into account the latest secant:  $J_k(\vec x_k-\vec x_{k-1})=f(\vec x_k)-f(\vec x_{k-1})$.

Derivations of BFGS updates seem far more involved and murky!  In particular, I'd like not to assume *a priori* that the update should be rank-2 or take a particular form.  Is there a short variational-looking motivation for the BFGS Hessian update like the one for Broyden?

Comment: If you'll allow an arbitrary update, then you could just use the full Hessian in Newton's method.  One major computational advantage of a low rank update is that it allows you to update the factorization of the approximate Hessian very quickly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The derivation of the BFGS is more intuitive when one considers (strictly) convex cost functionals:

However, some 
**background**  information is necessary: Assume, one wants to minimize a **convex** functional 
$$
f(x) \to \min_{x\in \mathbb R^n}.
$$ 
Say there is an approximate solution $x_k$. Then, one approximates the minimum of $f$ by the minimum of the truncated Taylor expansion
$$
f(x_k+p) \approx f(x_k) +\nabla f(x_k)^Tp + \frac{1}{2}p^T H(x_k)p. \quad(*)
$$
That is, one looks for $p$ such that $(*)$ is minimal and sets $x_{k+1} := x_k + p$. Computing the gradient of $(*)$ -- "with respect to $p$" -- and setting it to zero gives the relation
$$
H(x_k)[x_{k+1} - x_k] = \nabla f(x_{k+1}) - \nabla f(x_k),
$$
where $H$ is the 'Jacobian of the gradient' or the Hessian matrix.

Since the computation and inversion of the Hessian is expensive...

---

### ...**a short answer**

(cf. Broyden's update) might be that the BFGS update $H_{k+1}^{-1}$ minimizes
$$
\|H_k^{-1} - H^{-1}\|_W
$$
in a smartly chosen weighted Frobenius norm, subject to

1. $H[x_{k+1} - x_k] = \nabla f(x_{k+1}) - \nabla f(x_k)$ -- this is what one is out for -- and
2. $H^T = H$, because the Hessian is symmetric.

---

Then the choice of the weight $W$ in $\|H\|_W := \|W^{1/2}HW^{1/2}\|_F$ 
<strike>as the inverse of</strike> the averaged Hessian $G:=\int_0^1 H(x_k + \tau p) d\tau$, cf. [here](http://www.math.psu.edu/~anovikov/acm113/qn.pdf) for the statement but without proof, gives the [BFGS update formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) (with $\alpha_k = 1$).

**The major points are:**

- One tries to approximate the solution for the actual costs by the solution for a quadratic approximation
- Computation of the Hessian, and its inverse, is expensive. One prefers simple updates.
- The update is chosen optimal for the *inverse* rather than the actual Hessian.
- That it is a rank-2 update is a consequence of the particular choice of the weights in the Frobenius norm.

A **longer answer**, should include how to choose the weights, how to make this work for nonconvex problems (where a curvature condition appears that requires a scaling of the search direction $p$), and how to derive actual the formula for the update. A reference is [here](http://perso.unifr.ch/ales.janka/numeroptim/09_newton1.pdf) (in German).

Comment: Thanks so much, this is great (and more or less what I expected based on the discussion in Nocedal&Wright).  The one remaining question I have is: why do we choose $W$ and the norm as we do?  I get that it has to do with units, but there are lots of potential choice of $W$ and norms that do this.

Comment: Yes, true. Well, I don't know. One answer is that it gives the simple to compute and well working update formula. Historically, this approach to the update -- minimizing the difference in the update -- was the one by Shanno. It was a referee (Goldfarb) who found that a particular choice of the weights leads to the formula of Broyden and Fletcher. See this PhD thesis [Historical development of the BFGS secant method ...](http://scholarship.rice.edu/handle/1911/61898) for the intuitions of the developers of the BFGS. However, all 3 approaches are quite abstract.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the guidance!  My current writeup (with some math mistakes that need help) is here:  http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs205a-13-fall/assets/notes/chapter8.pdf  (if you would like credit for your help I'm happy to provide it -- please email me with suitable contact info)

Comment: @jan Why is your equation $$ H(x_k)[x_{k+1} - x_k] = \nabla f(x_{k+1}) - \nabla f(x_k)$$ and not $$H(x_{k+1})[x_{k+1} - x_k] = \nabla f(x_{k+1}) - \nabla f(x_k)?$$  Isn't the secant condition given by $H_{k+1}s_k =y_k$, where $s_k=x_{k+1}-x_k, y_k=\nabla f_{k+1}-\nabla f_k$. Thanks!